# How to Back previous activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities: A,B, and C.

In class A,

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),B.class);
i.putExtra("id", user);
startActivity(i);
```

In class B,

```
String u = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

 ---- bla bla bla ---

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),C.class);
i.putExtra("name", name);
i.putExtra("tel",tel);
startActivity(i);
```

Now I'm in "Activity C". How to I go back to "Activity B"? I'm trying place finish() but, ERROR "unfortunately, APPNAME has stopped." shows up and the background is "Activity A".

I want to go back to "B Activity".
Please help me.

Comment: Please add complete logcat

Comment: logcat is very use full to help you.. post logcat here

Comment: try onBackPressed() method or finish()

Comment: I think you are starting B again from C and getting NPE for bundle...just finish C, no need to start B again

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onBackPressed();` method to go back to previous activity...

put a button on Activity C's layput and put this `onBackPressed();`  on Buttons's click listener.. like below...

```
btn_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

This may help you..

Answer (score 0):

Try Using [Up Button](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#UpNav), this can be done by placing a attribute  `android:parentActivityName` (which needs to be set to your parent activity in your case B) in your `activity` element of the manifest file and by calling a `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` in your onCreate method of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Read these [Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp)

Then Do it like these:

**For Eg:**

**Activity A:**

```
public class Activitya extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override

       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
       position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");

       id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");

       name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
       final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

       getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

       }

    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: 
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
        }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
      }
```

**Activity B:**

In activity B you have to use a `intent` to go back to previous activity.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
         {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activitya.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);

    intent.putExtra("id", gallery.getGalId());
    intent.putExtra("name", gallery.getAlbumTitle());
    startActivity(intent);

    }
```